# What are ANBU called in other villages

Tags: naruto

Are they all just called anbu or do they have special divisions like the hidden leaf anbu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ANBU means Ansatsu Senjutsu Tokushu Butai(Special Assassination and Tactical Squad). It is a common name for any village.

As described in [ANBU wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Anbu),

> ANBU are covert operatives dispatched by their Kage.
>
> Anbu are recruited from their village's standard shinobi forces, hand-picked by their Kage for their individual capabilities and special skills.

As described in [ANBU's uniform](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Anbu#Uniform), the outfit are different but not what they are called. It is more like Kage which like post or title.

And yes they do have special division like [Hunter-nin](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hunter-nin) from The Village Hidden in the Mist.

Comment: Since the OP asked about special divisions as well, it might be good to reference another part of the wiki about different branches. Konoha has Root and Kirigakure has Hunter-Nin. *In Kirigakure, there is a special branch of Anbu known as hunter-nin*. There is additional information in the wiki